# Kudan in Unity: how to stop or reset markerless tracking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan, slam

I am creating an application with Kudan where a photograph (a 2D sprite) appears via markerless tracking. Based on the sample project I've successfully made adjustments so that the 2D plane is always perpendicular to the camera and placed on the screen in the position I want. Really wonderful!

But I am unable to figure out how to restart/reset the tracking via a script. I can always force the tracking to restart by blocking the camera or shaking the phone, but I want to do it via a button-- it is exactly the same behavior I've found described in the "ArbiTrack Basics" guide for Android and iOS, but am unable to reproduce it in Unity. To what script should I send a stop tracking command in order to get the tracking instance to restart (exactly the same effect as blocking the camera when running one of the sample Unity projects in Markerless Mode).

The situation is described here for Android coding: https://wiki.kudan.eu/ArbiTrack_Basics#Stopping_ArbiTrack

where it says to call these three things:

// Stop ArbiTrack
arbiTrack.stop();

// Display target node
arbiTrack.getTargetNode().setVisible(true);

//Change enum and label to reflect ArbiTrack state
arbitrack_state = ARBITRACK_STATE.ARBI_PLACEMENT;

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to do this-- though I'm not sure it's ideal.

Looking in the TrackingMethodMarkerless.cs script, it seems that the StopTracking() does not work-- it disables the updating of the tracking but doesn't actually disable the instance of detection.  But taking a note from it, I added an if statement to the ProcessFrame() function:

//

if (disableMarkerless == false)

trackable.isDetected = _kudanTracker.ArbiTrackIsTracking ();

else

trackable.isDetected = false;

//

Now, changing the disableMarkerless bool operator disables the tracking.

Comment: Yes, the object is only disabled when tracking is "lost", but not when it is stopped manually. This is something that can be changed for a future release.